# jQuery cycle.all.js first slide timeout

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I'm using the cycle.all.js jQuery plugin (http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). Right now it's working fine, but I need the first image to have a shorter timeout than all the rest. So when the user first hovers his mouse over the slideshow-div the cycle begins immediately, but after the first slide it changes the timeout to 650. This is how my code looks like right now:

```
$('div#slideshow').mouseenter(->
  $(this).cycle
    fx: "fade",
    speed: 1
    timeout: 650
  ).mouseleave ->
    $(this).cycle 'stop'
```

Comment: Just a note on your CS. `@` is mapped to `this` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `delay` option and give it a negative value:

```
$(this).cycle
    fx: "fade",
    speed: 1
    timeout: 650
    delay: -650
)
```

Note that this causes it to go *immediately* to the second slide, which I think is what you want, since the first image of the slideshow is already visible before the user hovers over it.

As Benjamin pointed out, in Coffeescript you can use `@` as a shortcut for `this`:

```
$('div#slideshow').mouseenter(->
  $(@).cycle
    fx: "fade",
    speed: 1,
    timeout: 650,
    delay: -650  //go to the next slide immediately
  ).mouseleave ->
    $(@).cycle 'stop'
```